# Probabilities and sets

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

question:

You own $5$ songs by Adele, $4$ by Lady Gaga, and $3$ by Katie Perry. How many playlists can be formed that consist of $3$ Adele, $2$ Gaga, and $2$ Perry songs if
(a) Repetitions are allowed (the same song may be played multiple times). (b) Repetitions aren’t allowed.

a) $5^3\times 4^2 \times 3^2 = 18 000$

b) $5^2\times 4^1\times 3^1 = 300$

Am i right?

Answer (score 0):

Your answer of part $a)$ is correct, but part $b)$, it should be $\binom{5}{3}\times \binom{4}{2}\times \binom{3}{2}=180$.

Comment: Thank you it's nice!

Comment: Your answer is for how many ordered playlists where very specifically the first three songs were by Adele, the next two by Gaga, and the final two songs in the playlist by Perry. The answer to (a) and (b) is incorrect if we allow the order in which artists appear to vary or mix as well as the answer to (a) is incorrect if we were to allow unordered lists.  Your answer to (b) is the correct answer if the list were unordered.