# How to distinguish between permutation and combination questions?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

You own 5 songs by Adele, 4 by Lady Gaga, and 3 by Katie Perry. How many
playlists (ordered list of songs) can be formed that consist of 3 Adele, 2 Gaga, and 2 Perry songs if:

(a) Repetitions are allowed?

(b) Repetitions are not allowed?

I am struggling on what questions I should ask myself when approaching a problem like this? Is this a permutation, or a combination? Or neither?

Comment: "*Is this a permutation, a combination, or neither?*"  Neither, but it can use both permutations and combinations as substeps in the larger problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Probabilities and sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2990233/probabilities-and-sets)

Comment: @lulu ironically, although older and an exact duplicate, the answer there is incorrect.  See my comment on user's deleted answer below.

Comment: @JMoravitz  That's funny!  I was struck by the exactness of the duplicate and did not look further.  I'll retract my close vote accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Pick which positions will be occupied by songs by Adele.

Among the remaining positions, pick which positions will be occupied by songs by Gaga.  The final remaining positions will be occupied by songs by Perry.

Now, among the positions designated to be occupied by Adele, pick which song occupies the first of those positions.  Then pick which song occupies the second of those positions (*noting that in the case of repetition not allowed, we have one fewer option*).

Continue in this manner until all is sorted out, giving final answers of $\binom{7}{3}\binom{4}{2}5^3\cdot 4^2\cdot 3^2$ for repetition allowed and $\binom{7}{3}\binom{4}{2}(5\cdot 4\cdot 3)\cdot (4\cdot 3)\cdot (3\cdot 2)$ for repetition not allowed.